# Error loading images in a new environment in Genexus 16

Tags: image, environment, genexus

When creating a new environment (Genexus 16), the compiled web panel and master page lose the src of inserted images and are generated with a code to replace the path.
It also happens with Date variable icons for selecting dates.

It does not work with any image except using a &image.fromUrl () variable. Doesn't work with &image.fromImage ()

To clarify things ... I have two more environments in the same project that work.

Has it happened to someone and has the solution?

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

Just try to press f5+ refreh. Could be an issue of cache.